# Get Sum and Id of record through Linq-to-SQL and display on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to convert this `SQL` statement to `linq` to `sql` in `MVC` code first.

```
SELECT SUM(OrderUnits), ProductID
FROM OrderProducts AS op
jOIN Orders AS o ON o.ID = op.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderStatus = 1
GROUP BY op.ProductID;
```

I have tried to no avail. I have method in my controller call `MostSoldItems` and I need to get this result and display it on my view.

This is what I tried:

```
var query =
    (from p in dbcontext.OrderProducts
    let totalQuantity = 
        (from op in dbcontext.Products
         join o in dbcontext.Orders on p.OrderID equals o.ID
         where o.OrderStatus == true
         select p.OrderUnits).Sum()
     orderby totalQuantity descending
     select p);
```

I'm not getting anything. and I do not know how I would go about displaying this on a view.

Comment: You can't get all the product back, just product ids:  `dbcontext.OrderProducts.Where(o => o.OrderStatus == 1).GroupBy(g => g.ProductID).Select(g => new {ProductID = g.Key,  Total = g.Sum()});`

Comment: @Candide this is not working I'm not getting any results

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a working piece of code. I have no idea of what your data looks like, or how your code infrastructure works. Use the code I gave you as a starting point to solve your problem, as it outlines how LINQ is meant to work.

Comment: @Candide oh okay I will try that... sorry I'm still figuring out a lot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I seem to have figured a work around of perhaps even a straight answer. Thanks for @candide 's answer I started working on it for a while and have figured it out! The below code works fine for my problem. Thanks @Moho also for his contribution.

```
var query = from p in dbcontext.OrderProducts
                    join pd in dbcontext.Orders on p.OrderID equals pd.ID
                    group p by p.ProductID into pdg
                    select new MostSoldModel
                    {
                        ID = pdg.Key,
                        Total = pdg.Sum(x => x.OrderUnits)
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the sum total of `OrderProduct.OrderUnits` filtered by the related `Order.OrderStatus == true` and grouped by product:

```
dbContext.OrderProducts
    .Where( op => op.Order.OrderStatus )
    .GroupBy( op => op.Product )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        Product = g.Key,
        TotalQuantity = g.Sum( op => op.OrderUnits ),
    } );
```

Comment: This isn't working unfortunately. No I'm trying to get the most sold product and the display it on my view